# php count on online server is different from my localhost

Tags: php, image, count

i use $count_files to loop through images and show those images bellow the main image of the post. on local server if there is 0 image count is 0 , if there is 1 image count is 1 etc.. (that's right). 
but on online server (linux host) even when there is no image it returns count as 1 , but for the rest it is correct for 1 is 1, for 2 is 2 etc..

```
$count_files = count(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$multiple_images_dir.'/*.jpg'));

for($i = 0; $i < ($count_files) ; $i++){

    $echoMultipleImage = '';
    //and some other related codes ..
    $echoMultipleImage .= '/'.($i+1).'.jpg" width="70px">' ; 

    echo $echoMultipleImage ;
}
```

even i tried with for($i = 1; $i <= $count_files .. but it reurns for
no images the number 1 ...

Comment: This calls for basic debugging: What does the `glob()` call output that makes `count()` assume there's one element in it? Use e.g. `print_r()`  to see what's in the resulting array.

Comment: with no image in there i tested print_r($count_files ) ; answer was 1  - then print_r() without count and glob showed below code: /home/brandbar/public_html/wp-content/uploads/multiple_images/*.jpg please note on local server count for no image is 0 , but on online server count for no image is 1 .. –  any idea help ..

Comment: Do print_r without count but with glob, what does it show? You can edit the result into your question.

Answer (score 0):

just simply change to this:

```
$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$multiple_images_dir.'/*.jpg');
if ($files){
  $count_files = count($files);
}
```

//if sb doesn't know the answer no need to mark it as negative !!